# Prove that if $g: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function such that $ g(i) p_{i j}=g(j) p_{j i}, \quad \forall i, j \in S $ then $g=c \pi$

Tags: markov-chains

I am terrible at writing proofs so I was wondering if someone could help me check if I am right or heading in the right direction.

**Problem**

Consider an irreducible Markov chain with finitely many states. Prove that if $g: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function such that
$$
g(i) p_{i j}=g(j) p_{j i}, \quad \forall i, j \in S
$$
then $g=c \pi$ where $c$ is a constant and $\pi$ is a stationary distribution.

**My attempt**

Reffering to the notes of by [Takis Konstantopoulos](https://mcube.nctu.edu.tw/%7Ecfung/docs/books/konstantopoulous2009_mcrw.pdf), p.59:

The detailed balance equations of an markov chain is equivalent to forming ratio a ratio of $\frac{p_{i j}}{p_{j i}}=\frac{g(j)}{g(i)}$ Therefore, multiplying by $g(i)$ and summing over $j$ we find
$$
g(i)=\sum_{j \in S} g(j) p_{j i}
$$

Hence, the function $g$ satisfies the balance equation and shows that the chain is reversible. This implies that:

$$
g(i) p_{i j}=\pi(j) p_{j i} 
$$

$$
g(i)=\pi(j) \frac{p_{j i}}{p_{i j}} => g = \pi * c
$$
where $c = \frac{p_{j i}}{p_{i j}} $